# CQRS in a data heavy application involving a lot of CRUD

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, cqrs

I've been developing a non-trivial personal application and I thought I'd use CQRS to learn it. The application is very data entry heavy, lots of entities and lots of forms. I find myself constantly creating CRUD queries/commands and their respective handlers plus DTO's and I find myself thinking...this is all very excessive.

- MyEntity
- GetMyEntityQuery/GetMyEntityQueryHandler
- GetMyEntitiesQuery/GetMyEntitiesQueryHander
- CreateMyEntityCommand/CreateMyEntityCommandHandler
- UpdateMyEntityCommand/UpdateMyEntityCommandHandler
- DeleteMyEntityCommand/DeleteMyEntityCommandHandler
- MyEntityDto

All of that above for each and every domain entity (not to mention mapping between commands, domain entities and dto's) that I have to interact with. Is this right? It feels a bit much, like am I missing something?

If I went a more bog standard route then I'd have:

- MyEntity
- MyEntityService
- MyEntityDto

Whereas at the moment I have upwards of 100 classes spread across commands, queries and handlers.

Comment: "Whereas at the moment I have upwards of 100 classes spread across commands, queries and handlers." Yeah that does seem to be a feature of this pattern. I think you have to ask yourself "am i using events?" "am i using a distributed database?"

Comment: The answer to both those questions is no, unfortunately. I'm assuming CQRS comes into its own when you do need to use domain events and use different data sources?

Answer (score 5):

I think you experience what Martin Fowler wrote in the first paragraph in his article about [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html):

> but beware that for most systems CQRS **adds risky complexity.**

and this complexity and the extra work which comes with it has to be justified by some **real needs**. Hence, for CQRS, there should be first one or more use cases for a read model as well as a write model (or CRUD model), and and these use cases should allow you to validate which of the operations are really required.

In theory, these two models should require only

- insert/update/delete commands on the "write model" side
- queries on the "read model" side

In reality, however, your read model may technically require some update operations as well, and your write model some read operations. But when you just created both as a duplicate of your existing data model for "learning purposes", with no other goal, it is actually not very astonishing that you now have to implement all of your CRUD code twice.

How can you solve this? Well, I see two possible line of actions:

- don't use such artificial constructs, where the whole read and write model are essentially the same. When both models look sufficiently different, a lot of the code for these models will look less like a duplicate. Or
- use a code generating approach, or some more general framework (similar to ORMs for CRUD). We use such techniques for decades to reduce boring CRUD code. A similar code generator or CQRS framework could generate all standard commands and standard queries from some meta description. I am sure such things already exists, but depending on your requirements, it may be actually not too hard to create such a generator on your own.

Answer (score 1):

> The application is very data entry heavy, lots of entities and lots of forms.

"Data Entry" -- especially CRUD data entry -- is not a particularly good fit for CQRS.  You tend to end up with a lot more ceremony in your code than is justified by your needs.

[Udi Dahan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhfyP8pEEc4&t=868s) offers this distinction

- Function (calculation without data)
- Database (data without specialized function)
- Service (data and specialized function together)

CQRS for databases tends to have poor return on investment.

Usually, if CQRS is going to be a good investment, you are already looking at how "what I write down next" is a function of "what new information has just arrived" and "what I have written down in the past".

This will normally include some flavor of "domain model" - in memory representations of both the new information and the old information so that one can calculate how the information is aggregated together.

The place where CQRS might fit? -- what *processes* are affected by the arrival of new data?  and what information are we using to keep track of those processes?

Answer (score 0):

CQRS is often confused/amalgamated with Event Sourcing, but at its heart the goal of the pattern is just to separate reads and writes. You don't need all those commands

Say for example you have a highly read database which also needs to run big batch updates. The reads often deadlock with the writes so you wan to separate it into two databases. one that you write to, which then replicates to multiple 'read only' databases which serve the read requests.

You don't need all the command classes for that, you can just have separate read and write repository classes that point at the different databases.

If however you have a big distributed nosql database and message queues where the consistency of reads and writes is not always guaranteed you might need to manually resolve the order in which events take place. You can't just rely on the time order of things staying correct through the system.

For example I have a products db, I add a new product and the update its price. If I process these two commands in a random order as simple `Upserts` then what price the database holds at the end is not determined. It just depends on whichever ran last.

In this case its useful to have separate Commands,`AddProduct` and `UpdatePrice` with some extra meta data. Now when these commands make their way through various queues and offline processing to finally hit your database you can say.. hang on a price update for a product that doesn't exist? put that back on the queue for later.

Even in this case though I would advise putting all the information in the Event/Command This cuts down on classes, you can just have a generic `Command<>` style class to cover most things, and plays to the strengths of event driven systems by allowing new, unknown functionality to be triggered by events. Such as: every time a price updates email an alert with the product name in it etc

```
public class Command<T>()
{
     public string CommandName {get;set}
     public T Data {get;set;}
     //extra meta data as required..
     date?
     id?
     user?
     sequence?
}
```

Comment: In your Command<T> example, is string Type denoting an Insert or Update or it is the actual Type of T Data? Also, is this suitable for queries too?

Comment: its a string name for the command, so when you serialise it you know what it is - changed it to CommandName